# Use a QPixmap as OpenGL texture

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, textures, pixmap

I am writing a qt code in c++, including some openQL graphics (QGLWidget).

I would like to assign a QPixmap as texture to an openGL quad. Is this possible ?

Comment: Convert the pixmap to `QImage`, upload the image's data (`constBits()`) into a texture, draw the quad?

Answer (score 3):

Use class [QOpenGLTexture](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopengltexture.html)

In article youwill see short example.

Comment: Note that QOpenGLTexture is 'since 5.2' and many projects are still (stuck) at pre 5.0 era.